# Can I automate apple pay using the safari mobile user agent

Tags: javascript, ios, puppeteer, applepay

I have an e-commerce application that uses google play and apple pay for payments. And I develop automation suites using Puppeteer.
With google play, I faced no issue, but for the apple pay, you need to use Safari.
I use the user agent to say the application that users come form iOS safari:
`await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/83.0.4103.88 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");`
But that does not help. I not see the apple pay button.

It is really possible to do Apple Pay payments using Puppeteer? Because I can not find any question about it.

Comment: Hey Tomash, could you please share how you managed to automate google pay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suppose it is not possible at the moment. The closest you can get to simulate a real iOS device is not with puppeteer, but with [microsoft/playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) which is a successor of puppeteer (made by the same team as puppeteer back then at Google) and it supports **WebKit browser engine.**

If I visit https://applepaydemo.apple.com/ with an emulated iPhone 11 device it gives:

> Your browser or device does not support Apple Pay on the web.
> To try out this demo, open this page in Safari on a compatible device.

You can test it here without local npm install: https://try.playwright.tech/

```js
const playwright = require('playwright')

async function fn() {
  const { webkit, devices } = playwright
  const iPhone11 = devices['iPhone 11 Pro']
  const browser = await webkit.launch()
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    viewport: iPhone11.viewport,
    userAgent: iPhone11.userAgent,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
  })

  const page = await context.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://applepaydemo.apple.com/')
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example-iphone.png' })
  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```

I am not aware of any workarounds at the moment to make Apple Pay work with non-iOS devices.